# rzc generate exited with code -2147450730

Tags: build, compiler-errors, blazor, setup-project, blazor-client-side

After I created the blazor application in Visual studio . When i trying to run or build the application am getting this error.

I used `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was the fix for me https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20857

If you check the build ouput window, you might see a more useful error like:

[image: Build output error]

This showed that I needed to install the lastest .NET runtime from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score 4):

For me, installing 2.1 SDK did the trick. Here is the link to it: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.1

Comment: I was setting up new laptop and the VS 2019 installation only installed SDK 5. Existing projects using Core 2.0 were erroring out during the build. This solved it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Visual Studio to 2019 v16.9.2 and that fixed it for me.
I also read another post where repairing the VS installation fixed the problem.
My problem started mysteriously after everything had been working for some time, so I don't think it was an issue with the version. I think just running the upgrade repaired the installation.